# Hibernate/(Shutdown with fast-startup) in windows 10 doesn't work. Only complete shutdown/restart works

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, shutdown, hibernate, win10-fast-startup

I recently updated my windows 10 to v2004. But now whenever I try to shutdown(with fast startup enabled) or hibernate, the screen goes blank and goes to the lock screen. (**I don't want to disable fast startup or do force shutdown everytime or reset/refresh my os install**)

I think the cause of the issue is similar  to the one in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3211190/fast-startup-causes-hibernation-or-shutdown-to-fail-in-windows-10-wind). But I didn't have any warning with event id 45.

But I see there is an warning in event viewer after the shutdown is initiated. [event log](https://pastebin.com/FCbEuBV5)

```
Description:
A corrected hardware error has occurred.
 
Component: PCI Express Root Port
Error Source: Advanced Error Reporting (PCI Express)
 
Primary Bus:Device:Function: 0x0:0x1C:0x5
Secondary Bus:Device:Function: 0x0:0x0:0x0
Primary Device Name:PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D15&SUBSYS_08291028&REV_F1
```

I located the device to be qualcomm wireless driver and tried updating and uninstalling it.
But the issue stayed.

Another fact that makes me think its the driver causing the problem is that I can perfectly hibernate or (shutdown with fast startup enabled) in safe mode.

*All my drivers are up to date with no issues in functionality. I have tried windows troubleshooter, startup repair, changing boot-order but no help so far.*